# Import CSV/JSON in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I am using jade as a template engine for a static website, so I am not using any express server.
I'd like to import a csv or json file to load the data in my template. It can very easily be done using an express server but I don't know how to do this without one.

As a temporary solution, I load the data manually like this:

```
- var arr = []
- arr.push(['hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar'])
- arr.push(['hello1', 'world1', 'foo1', 'bar1'])
- arr.push(['hello2', 'world2', 'foo2', 'bar2'])
- arr.push(['hello3', 'world3', 'foo3', 'bar3'])
- arr.push(['hello4', 'world4', 'foo4', 'bar4'])

- for (var i; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  div
     h1=arr[i][0]
     // some more jade
- }
```

Instead, I am looking for something like this:

```
- var arr = require('./data.csv')

- for (var i; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  div
     h1=arr[i][0]
     // some more jade
- }
```

Is there any way to do this in jade?

Many thanks

Comment: require is typically found in nodejs however there are a couple third party apps which extend this ability to the browser such as browserfyjs however I am not sure if jade will have access to those plugins as they aren't usable until code hits client side. if jade is installed on your server I'm assuming its running as a sort of preprocessor which in that situation it wouldn't have access to window functions on compile. not sure about this but if your using php to call jade compiler you can get the csv in php parse it to an array and then pass it to jade. or use JSON and pass the json to jade

Comment: I see that you are not using Express, but are you using Node.js to serve the template?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for right ?  https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/3012

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jade Docs](http://jade-lang.com/api/):

In Node:

```
var list = require('./list.json'),
    jade = require('jade');

// Compile a function
var fn = jade.compileFile('./index.js', options);

// Render the function
var html = fn(list);

// serve html response however you currently serve rendered jade
```

Where locals would be your imported object.